# I'm trying to create a pygame window and responding to user input

Tags: python, pygame, typeerror, self, positional-argument

Here is my source code:

```
import sys  
import pygame  
from settings import Settings  

class AlienInvasion:    
    """Overall class to manage game assets and behavior."""    

    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize the game, and create game resources."""
        pygame.init()

        #self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 800))
        #pygame.display.set_caption('Alien Invasion')
        self.bg_color = (230, 230, 230)
        self.settings = Settings()

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.settings.screen_width, self.settings.screen_height))
        pygame.display.set_caption('Alien Invasion')

    def run_game(self):
        """Start the main loop for the game."""
        while True:
            # watch for keyboard and mouse events.
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    sys.exit()

            # Redraw the screen during each pass through the loop.
            self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)


            # make the most recently drawn screen visible.
            pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    # make a game instance, and run the game.  
    a1 = AlienInvasion  
    a1.run_game()
```

When I run the program, I got a `TypeError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\franc\Desktop\pyprojects\game_project\alien_invasion.py", line 38, in <module>
    a1.run_game()
TypeError: AlienInvasion.run_game() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

I imported the `sys` and `pygame` modules, and created a class with an `__init__()` method followed by rest of the code. At the end of the file, I created an instance of the class, and then called `run_game()`. I was expecting it to show a blank window screen.

Comment: Instead of explaining what you think the code does, please read [ask] and [mre] and **show** code that demonstrates the problem. We can only possibly analyze what we actually see. Please also read the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) in order to understand how to post code and errors properly.

Answer (score -2):

That error typically occurs when you call a method of a class on the class rather than an instance of that class. Instead of doing that, try this:

```
obj = AlienInvasion()
obj.run_game()
```

Also, could you try adding all your code?

Comment: Please read [answer] and do not attempt to answer questions that are missing crucial details. If you need to make guesses about what happened in order to answer, the question does not meet standards; and if you find yourself asking for more information then definitely do not answer. You have almost reached the point where the site will allow you to comment on questions to ask for this information. Similarly, questions that are about common problems that every beginner runs into should be *flagged* to be closed as duplicates, not answered fresh.